# Performance tuning an update statement in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have 2 update statements. when executed both together is taking more than 12hrs from SSIS. All the indexes on this tables were disabled before executing this update statements. I need to improve the performance. I need suggestions:

1) First update statement

```
Update Db1.table1
Set Db1.table1.col1 = Db2.table2.col1
from Db1.table1, Db2.table2
where Db1.table1.col2 = Db2.table2.col2
```

2) Second update statement

```
update table1
set table1.col3 = 0
from table1
where table1.col3 is null
```

Can update in batches help improving the performance of 1st update statement?
I see having a default on col3 is sufficient instead of running the second update. But I am not sure if it effects insert queries. The table is having a lot of data. I am not sure of altering the table to include default value on a column where table is having a lot of data.

Please provide your suggestions to performance tune the above statements. PLease also note that I am not having proper permissions on the DB to verify the execution plan.

Comment: Why did you delete the indexes? Db1.table1.col2 and Db2.table2.col2 should be indexed at least. This will speed up the join required to update the table. Finally if you don't have rights to profile your queries you should give the work to someone who has the rights they need to do the job.

Comment: Indexes are disabled before inserting data to the table for better performance. And after inserts and then this update statement, we are enabling the indexes. However, there are neither clustered nor non-clustered indexes on these columns in both the tables currently.

Answer (score 2):

When running the 1st Statement you should:

- have a clustered index on table1.col2
- have a clustered index on table2.col2

Be ware: you can only have 1 clustered index per table (because this index says how to physically store the data) and it HAS TO BE THE FIRST INDEX created on a table (vice-versa: the last one you delete)

coorect order of actions:

1. create table
2. create clustered index (unique or not, doesn't matter)
3. create nonclustred indexes

respectively:

1. delete nonclustered indexes
2. delete clustered index
3. drop table

Answer (score 2):

First, it would help to know which update is taking longer.  But, indexes are not necessarily your enemy when doing updates.

The first update:

```
Update t1
    Set t1.col1 = t2.col2
    from Db1.table1 t1 join
         Db2.table2 t2
         on t1.col2 = t2.col2;
```

This update really needs an index on `db2.table2(col2)`.  Otherwise, it will need to do a nested loop join.

The second update:

```
update table1
set table1.col3 = 0
from table1
where table1.col3 is null
```

is a bit trickier.  You are updating the column in the `where` clause.  My sense is that if relatively few of the values are `null` -- up to a few percent -- then an index on `table1(col3)` would help.  If many of the columns are null, then an index would be less useful.  Without an index, this requires a full table scan and should not be absurdly slow.

You may find that batching the updates on this table would help performance.

Comment: Good answer. I would also recommend keeping the default value on col3, if this eliminates the need for the 2nd update. The overhead of setting the default value with every table insert is negligible.